# Div element displayed outside the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a peculiar problem. I have designed the following layout. The layout displays according to my wish but the when i inspect the header div i find that the `logo` and `navigation` divs are shown outside the the highlighted part on moving cursor to header div.

[link to image for reference](http://i43.tinypic.com/2v0bj36.png)

Shouldn't the logo and navigation div be within the highlighted part as they are within the header div in code?? Or is that I am doing something wrong.

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo" style="float:left;" >Sample Text</div>
                <div id="navigation" style="float:right">
                    <ul style="text-decoration:none;">
                        <li>Page 1</li>
                        <li>Page 2</li>
                        <li>Page 3</li>
                        <li>Page 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="features" style="clear:both;margin-top:15px;">
                <p>....Lorem Ipsum Part...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I used the following minimal css

```
body{
    background-image : url('../images/bg-body.gif');
    background-repeat : repeat;
    font-family : Georgia;
    color : white;
}
#container{
    margin : auto;
    width : 960px;
}

#logo{
    font: 48px 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FCFAFA;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ededed, 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);*/
}
#header{
    margin-top : 20px;
}
li{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Set `overflow: auto;` on header and it'll be fine.

Comment: @jeevan it worked ! thanks .can u explain in short what was the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to 'clear' your floats to adjust the container height. So if you set

```
overflow: auto;
```

on the container, in your case the `header` it will 'encapsulate' it's floated children. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) is a good tutorial if you want to learn more.

Comment: @MayurBuragohain You can accept it as the answer if it helped. Cheers.